# About Java spring MimeMessageHelper send email with images

Tags: java, spring, mime-message

I have images on my file server which I want to embed into my email.

I can send email with local images like this way

```
message.addInline("image1", new ClassPathResource("../../static/images/123.jpg"));
```

but if i want to send email with my file server images, won't work.

```
message.addInline("image1", new ClassPathResource("http://fileserver.com/images/123.jpg"));
```

Anybody knows there is a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `http://fileserver.com/images/123.jpg` is no Class Path Resource.

If you access the image from the file system then file access classes from `java.io` package.
If you really need to to access the files over http, then you need to download the file first.

```
Url url = new URL("http://fileserver.com/images/123.jpg");
InputStream is = u.openStream();
...
```

Answer (score 2):

This question is a year old, but I want to contribute for help other people...

Spring have ways to do the job that you want. Take a look in this [chapter of the Spring 3x reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch26s03.html). [Or Spring2x](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/mail.html#mail-javamail-mime-attachments-inline).

In resume: 
You can obtain your image file from file file system of the server. As you can see in the reference:

```
Resource res = new FileSystemResource(new File("c:/Sample.jpg"));
helper.addInline("identifier1234", res);
```

Or from a relative path of the classpath of your application:

```
Resource res = new ClassPathResource("mx/blogspot/jesfre/test/image.png");
```

**But, if you want to send a resource from a file server with a URL, you can do something like @Ralph said:**

```
Url url = new URL("http://fileserver.com/images/123.jpg");
Resource res = new InputStreamResource(u.openStream());
```

And then, simply add the resource to your message:

```
helper.addInline("myIdentifier", res);
```

Hope this help somebody...